# Difference between Temporary rootdir and bindir in sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am not able to get the difference between Temporary rootdir and bindir in sqoop job.

can anyone explain this, it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both "working" directories, one has code generated objects, the other has temporary files from HDFS work

> `--bindir <dir>`  Output directory for compiled objects

> `--temporary-rootdir <dir>`   HDFS directory for temporary files created during import (overrides default "_sqoop")

For more information check out the SqoopUserGuide:
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html